# Using recaptcha in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, recaptcha

I'm trying to add in my site a reCaptcha, I have a key already but when i add in the div it returns an error.

> div vc-recaptcha theme="'light'" key="'key-number-here'"

In the recaptcha shows that:
ERROR for site owner: Invalid key type

I'm trying to use in localhost and I already register in here:
https://www.google.com/recaptcha

Comment: Do you really need to add single quotes around your attribute value ?

Comment: You should search before asking any question by the way check ([Recaptcha in Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453979/recaptcha-in-angular-js))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure  you add **localhost** (with port number if you are using) in your **domain settings** and you dont need extra quotes in the key

```
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key"></div>
```

and make sure you import the following library in your html code

```
 <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

Comment: how can I add localhost with port? when I try add localhost:52360 as new domain, this error has shown to me:
""The following domains are invalid: localhost:52360. A valid domain requires a host and must not include any protocol, path, port, query or fragment""

Comment: localhost domains are no longer supported by default https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#localhost_support